# Single file/class to store constants in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, constants

I have a ASP.NET web application which has more than 100 pages. Each page is using some common values ( ex : current USDoller rate) .This can be changed at any time. Now I want to maintain this value in a single file so that i can change only her at any time to get it reflected throughtout the project.I dont want to store it in web config. I want to store it in some other place

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a static class like this:

```
public static class MyConsts {
   public const string Prefix = "n-";
}
```

From anywhere in your project use:

```
MyConsts.Prefix
```

(Note: `const` is implicitly static)

Answer (score 4):

My initial thoughts are one of the following:

1. Store it in a database table and create a mechanism for editing the values
2. Create a static class and store them there

Comment: Additional benefit to #1: you can make configuration changes at runtime, assuming you cache the settings for a finite period of time and then expire them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a static class and store the constants there.  That way when you change it, everything will get the new values.